Finishing Hunter's Journal after Infected Crossroads
I didn't finish all of the Hunter's Journal entries for the Crossroads enemies before I obtained a dreamer and almost all of the enemies morphed into their infected versions.
I am specifically missing Leaping Husk, Aspid Mother, Gruzzer, and Husk Warrior.
Is it possible to get any of them anywhere else, even if it requires a lot of grinding one enemy spawn?

I believe all of the pre-infection Crossroads enemies can still be found after Infection, but I'm not about to list all of them.  Do you have any specific enemies you're wondering about?

@jwodder I put them in the answer.

@Daemons by answer, you mean question.

@User23415 Ah yes, I did mean that.

Each of the linked wiki pages has map images annotated with locations where those enemies can be found. Have you checked each of those locations?

All enemies from the Forgotten Crossroads can also be found in the Infected Crossroads, specifically so that you can still get the Hunter's Journal entries. Specifically:

Leaping Husks can be found to the left of the elevator shaft
Aspid Mothers can be found in the room with the acid that connects to Fungal Wastes
Gruzzers can be found to the lower left of the big vertical shaft room with all the platforms in it
Husk Warriors can be found to the upper left of the room that leads to the tram

